# SQL Server Last week from sun to sat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get date from Sun to sat of last week my code is,

```
Declare
      @now DateTime, @fmWeek DateTime, @toWeek DateTime

Set @now = GetDate()
Set @fmWeek = Convert(DateTime, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @now), -1))
Set @toWeek = DATEADD(ms,-3,Convert(DateTime, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0,  @now), 6)))

select @fmWeek, @toWeek
```

It shows me data from `2018-04-15 00:00:00.000` to `2018-04-21 23:59:59.997`

I need to get dates from previous week sun to sat not the same week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to get dates from previous week sun to sat not the same week*

I would just substract 7 days:

```
Declare @now DateTime = GetDate()
    ,@fmWeek DateTime, @toWeek DateTime;

Set @fmWeek = DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @now), -1) - 7;
Set @toWeek = DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @now), 5) - 7;
select @fmWeek, @toWeek;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2d253c1f4f86800acc1d1c2b668da860)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only two dates, @lad2025 have given you the correct query to get the dates.

In case you want to show all the dates bewteen these two days, you can try like following.

```
Declare @now DateTime = GetDate()
    ,@fmWeek DateTime, @toWeek DateTime;

Set @fmWeek = DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @now), -1) - 7;
Set @toWeek = DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @now), 5) - 7;

SELECT @fmWeek + RN AS DATE FROM
(   
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))-1 RN 
    FROM   master..[spt_values] T1
) T 
WHERE RN <= DATEDIFF(DAY,@fmWeek,@toWeek)
```

Output:

```
Date
------------------------
2018-04-08 00:00:00.000
2018-04-09 00:00:00.000
2018-04-10 00:00:00.000
2018-04-11 00:00:00.000
2018-04-12 00:00:00.000
2018-04-13 00:00:00.000
2018-04-14 00:00:00.000
```